# Generic image class with generic data type in C#

Tags: c#, image, generics

I would like to create generic image class with generic data type as shown in the code below.

In this implementation the thing I do not like is that I have to declare class like:
`Image<BGR<byte>, byte> a;`

instead of:

```
Image<BGR, byte> a;
```

Is there any way to accomplish this ?

```
public interface IColor<T>
{ }

public struct BGR<T>: IColor<T>
{
    public T B;
    public T G;
    public T R;
}

public class Image<TColor, T> where TColor: IColor<T>
{
    TColor[,] data;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Image<BGR<byte>, byte> a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `IColor` generic?

Comment: Why don't you like that? :-) I mean if you like Image<BGR, T> then you can implicitly like Image<BGR<T1>, T>! in both cases you provide a type.

Comment: IColor is generic because there is ore than one color type like HSV, BGR, LSV... which has pixel data type set as T.

Comment: @dajuric: But `IColor` doesn't have any members, does it?

Comment: No it does not. If you have another concept please share with me. The only condition is that I am able to write Image<BGR, byte> or Image<Bgr<byte>> instead Image<Bgr<byte>, byte>.

Answer (score 2):

All I've done is made `IColor` non-generic, and followed that through:

```
public interface IColor
{ }

public struct BGR<T>: IColor
{
    public T B;
    public T G;
    public T R;
}

public class Image<TColor> where TColor: IColor
{
    TColor[,] data;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Image<BGR<byte>> a;
    }
}
```

The fact that there are different `BGR`s depending on a type `T` **needn't** mean that all `IColor` implementations have to depend on a type `T`. There could be `IColor` implementations with zero, 2, or 9 type parameters - as long as they meet the actual contract of `IColor` (which is easy to do...), they are OK.

Answer (score 1):

- Code

  ```
  public interface IColor<T> {
      IColor<U> FromColor<U>(IColor<U> color);
  }

  public class Bgr: IColor<byte>, IColor<int> /* .. more IColor<T> */ {
      public IColor<T> FromColor<T>(IColor<T> color) {
          if(null==color)
              return default(Bgr<T>);

          if(color is Bgr)
              return color;

          if(color is Bgr<T>)
              return new Bgr {
                  Value=color
              } as IColor<T>;

          throw new NotImplementedException();
      }

      public object Value;
  }

  public struct Bgr<T>: IColor<T> {
      IColor<U> IColor<T>.FromColor<U>(IColor<U> color) {
          if(null==color)
              return default(Bgr<U>);

          if(color is Bgr)
              return (Bgr<U>)(color as Bgr).Value;

          if(color is Bgr<U>)
              return color;

          throw new NotImplementedException();
      }

      public T B, G, R;
  }

  public class Image<TColor, T> where TColor: IColor<T>, new() {
      public static Array CreateArray(params int[] lengths) {
          var color=(new TColor()).FromColor(default(TColor));
          return Array.CreateInstance(color.GetType(), lengths);
      }

      public Image(params int[] lengths) {
          data=Image<TColor, T>.CreateArray(lengths);
      }

      public Array data; // expose for test
  }
  ```
- Test

  ```
  public class TestClass {
      public static void TestMethod() {
          var image=new Image<Bgr, byte>(640, 480);
          var data=(Bgr<byte>[,])image.data;
          var bgr=new Bgr<byte>();
          bgr.B=123;
          data[0, 0]=bgr;
          data[0, 0].G=124;
          bgr=data[0, 0];
          Console.WriteLine("bgr{{B={0}, G={1}, R={2}}}", bgr.B, bgr.G, bgr.R);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: I need to constrain TColor to IColor not to particular color. But thank you.

Comment: Thank you. But there will be more color types like Bgr, Bgra, Hsv, Lsv.... I will need to put constrain (struct) on pixel type of each color type but in core interface IColor. Esentially I would like to have similar implementation like EmguCV's but with one big exception that all Color classes are generic ones. Does this seem to you like a good concept or do you propose something else for this problem ?